# Where should I customize the "Sorry, no quotes are available..." message?

Tags: magento-1.8, localisation, messages

The full message is "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time." but I see it in eleven locations in the source code!   Where do I change it for my own custom message, I hope not in all the locations.

Although I'm not trying to change the language, I wonder if this is related to localization, and maybe there is only one place I need to make the change?

Answer (score 0):

You can change translations for any language, this includes the default US English. There are two different ways to change core translations:

### 1. Using theme specific translations

You can define custom translations in your theme, create the following file if it does not exist yet:

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv
```

(replace `en_US` if you use a different language)

Note that this should be a project specific theme, not `rwd/default` or `some_bought_theme/default`. If you did not already, you can add a child theme next to `default` and specify this one as theme in the system configuration. You don't need to copy anything from the `default` directory since Magento falls back automatically, so you only need to add the files that are customized.

In the `translate.csv` you can add your custom translations. Since the translated string is "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time." and it's coming from the `Mage_Sales` module, you need to add this line:

```
"Mage_Sales::Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.","your custom translation here"
```

### 2. Using the "inline translation" feature

As a store manager you can change translations using the "Inline Translation" feature.

#### Summarizing the [documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/design/interface-text-change.html?Highlight=inline%20translation):

> 1. **Add Your IP Address to the Developer Mode Whitelist** (System > Configuration > Developer)
> 2. **Disable Output Caches** (System > Cache Management)
> 3. **Activate the Translate Inline Tool** (System > Configuration > Developer)
> 4. **Update the Text** (Click the [image: book] icon next to any text in the frontend that you want to change)
> 5. **Restore Original Settings**

This will save the custom translation in the database for the selected store and theme.